# Reference local project during development, nuget project when deployed

Tags: .net, f#, nuget, paket

I'm developing [a library](https://github.com/deecewan/Forest) for F#.
It contains 3 projects, each of which are delivered in different packages (One is a core requirement for consumers, the others are optional). It looks like this:

```
src/
  - ConsoleWriter/
    - ConsoleWriter.fsproj
  - FileWriter/
    - FileWriter.fsproj
  - Forest
    - Forest.fsproj
```

So, `Forest` is standalone, which is fine. `ConsoleWriter` and `FileWriter` both depend on `Forest`. In the `fsproj` for the writers, I have

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Forest\Forest.fsproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

so that I can reference the most up to date `Forest` during development. However, I think I then need to add the dependency to the package on nuget when creating the new `ConsoleWriter` package. Is there a way to do this with `paket`?

I don't want to always depend on the remote version, because it becomes problematic if I'm updating more than one at the same time.

Edit: I've just seen this on the [`paket.template` docs](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/template-files.html)

> In a project file, the following dependencies will be added:
>
> - ...
> - Any **project reference** with a matching `paket.template` file with a minimum version requirement of the version currently being packaged.

(emphasis mine). Does that imply that it already does exactly what I'm asking for?

Edit 2: Just done a test with `paket generate-nuspec` and it does *not* contain the `Forest` dependency.

Comment: Does Forest have a paket.template?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the remote version as a regular dependency, then use a [paket.local file](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/local-file.html) to override it with your locally-edited version during development.

The example use case on the linked page looks like the same thing you're trying to do, if I have understood you correctly.